# Importing Text File to Database Causes Out of Space Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, dts

When I try to import Text File into SQL Server 2000 using DTS, it gives me the following error

> Not enough storage available to complete this operation

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](http://bytes.com/groups/ms-sql/83616-sql-server-2000-not-enough-storage-available-complete-operation):

> As it turns out the problem lies with the DTS wizard when importing text files it set the fields as varchar and a size of 8000!!!!!!!
>
> I changed them (all 236 of them) to 255 and hey presto!